# How to get the probability values from a histogram matlab

Tags: matlab, math, histogram, probability

This a math/matlab question

I have a data set of angles ranging from -180 to 180

I then make a histogram of the data set using the code

```
histogram(angles)
```

I want to use the probabilities from the histogram for another plot for the equation

```
ln(probabilty of angle) = constant(angle) + constant
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the values for probabilities for the angles from -180 to 180 from the histogram.

I've read that I need to normalize my histogram but from there I am not sure what to do

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the equation? Empirical probability is #events/#total events, don't understand what that constant is.

Comment: well the constant(angle) or slope would be equal to a measure in chemistry known as delta G or free energy and the the other constant or B is irrelevant in the fitting of the equation, or so I am told. I want to get the a list of the angle and the probability for that angle from the histogram if possible for -180 to 180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `hist()` will normalise for you with its 3rd parameter:

```
x = rand(1000, 1)*360-180;
[probas, angles] = hist(x, -180:10:180, 1.0);
bar(angles, probas);
```

You might want to combine values of bin -180 and +180
Now `angles` and `probas` are available for other plots.